# Assignment operator concatenating instead of copying

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm having a hard time figuring out my assignment operator in a specific case.  I have two arrays of objects, one in the other.  I'm reading information in from a file, some of which is stored in the top-level object, and some stored its array.  When I sort these using '=', the information in the inner array seems to be concatenated with whatever was there before instead of replacing it.

```
class TopLevel
{
public:
  TopLevel();
  TopLevel(const TopLevel &);
  ~TopLevel();
  const TopLevel& operator=(const TopLevel &);
private:
  InnerLevel *inlevel[8];
  int numObjectsInArray;

class InnerLevel
{
public:
  InnerLevel();
  InnerLevel(const InnerLevel &);
  ~InnerLevel();
  const InnerLevel& operator=(const InnerLevel &);
private:
  string var1;
  string var2;
```

Here is the assignment operator

```
const TopLevel& TopLevel::operator=(const TopLevel &right )
{
  if ( &right != this ) 
  {
    numObjectsInArray = right.numObjectsInArray;
    for ( int i = 0; i < right.numObjectsInArray; i++ )
      *inlevel[i] = *right.inlevel[i]; 
  }
  return *this;
}
```

The assignment operator in InnerLevel is pretty simple

```
const InnerLevel& InnerLevel::operator=( const InnerLevel &right )
{
  if ( &right != this )
  {
    var1 = right.var1;
    var2 = right.var2;
  } 
  return *this;
}
```

I am reading from the file and sorting as I go...

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  if (conditions for numeric sort)
    break;

for(int j = count - 1; j >= i; --j)
    tplevel[j + 1] = tplevel[j];
```

At the end of the file reading, I am printing the whole mess.  Lets say I have two object in tplevel each with 2 objects in InnerLevel.  tplevel[2] is:

```
2  aaaaa  aaaaa
2  bbbbb  bbbbb
```

and tplevel[1] is

```
1  ccccc  ccccc
1  ddddd  ddddd
```

What I end up with for tplevel[2], after the sort, is:

```
2  aaaaa  aaaaa  
2  bbbbb  bbbbb
2  ccccc  ccccc  
2  ddddd  ddddd
```

I just want index 1 to be copied to 2, not added to it... any ideas whats going on?

Comment: What's your code for printing? Considering the array is a fixed size, it's unlikely that it's concatenating without corrupting anything.

Comment: At most, the array is only filled with 5 objects, so never reaches 8.

Comment: The printing uses << overloading, something liek ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const TopLevel &a ).  Its a cascade of 3 objects

Comment: It could be problem with the operator= on InnerLevel.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but its really simple.  I added an example above